# Passport request from IRCC through the VAC office

Tags: 90-180-visa-rules

I have received mail stating that I need to submit my passport for the Tourist Visa.  My nearest VAC Office is Tanzania, however, I am not sure how much I should pay to send the passport as I had already paid for my application submission online.

Secondly, can I pay electronically? If not, who should I make the Bank Draft payable to?

Comment: The instruction given in the mail you received should be clear. If you've been granted a visa I would expect the costs to be part of what you have already paid. However, you will need to pay for reliable shipping both ways - again, instructions should have been in the mail you have. You haven't specified which country you're applying to - IRCC implies Canada, but your choice of tag implies a Schengen visa. Post an image of the letter with your personal details blanked out and we might be able to say more.